# Avoid refetching same data on parent and child loaders

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

In Remix, I have the following structure:

```
routes
|-- teams.tsx
|-- teams.$id.tsx
root.tsx
```

The files `teams.tsx` and `teams.$id.tsx` need to fetch the same data from an API.
If I only have one result in `teams.tsx`, I have to redirect directly to `teams.$id.tsx`

As the loader of `teams.tsx` is called in parallel with the loader of the child `teams.$id.tsx`, I actually have 2 calls made to the API which is not good.
How to avoid refetching the same data in `teams.$id.tsx`?

I have tested `useMatch` to get data in the child but I encounter a problem with the `remix-toast` library to redirect to `teams.tsx`

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
> Promise])

I think it can only be called from the loader while hooks can only be called from the body...

What I'm trying to achieve:

- In route `"/teams"`, I called the API to get all teams

  - If I only have one result, I have to redirect to `teams.id.tsx`
  - If many results, I display them
- In route `"/teams/$id"`, I just want to call the API once (in `teams.tsx`) and share data in `teams.$id.tsx`

  - I need to loop on data to find a match with `$id`

    - If no result found, I have to redirect to `teams.tsx` with message "not team found"
    - If one result found, I display the informations of the team

How to get this?

-EDIT-

Here is more code and explanations to a better understand:

- `teams.tsx`

  - fetch API data + session
  - if only one result, redirect to `teams.$id.tsx`
  - if more than one, display teams
- `teams.$id.tsx`

  - fetch the **exact same data** as the parent loader (so 2 calls made to the API instead of just one)
  - need to loop on data to match an ID and display result

    - if no result, redirect to `teams.tsx`
    - If a match is found, display team informations

**File teams.tsx**

```
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {

    // session
    const session = await sessionStorage.getSession(request.headers.get('Cookie'));

    if (!session.get('token')) {
        return redirectWithToast(`/`, { message: "You don’t have access!", type: "error" } )
    }

    // data
    const teams = await fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

    if (teams.length === 1) {
        [...]
        return redirect(`/teams/${teamsId}`);
    }

    return { session, teams };
}

export default function Teams() {
    const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

    console.log(data.session)
    console.log(data.teams)
}
```

**File teams.$id.tsx**

```
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {

    // ALL DATA ARE THE SAME AS IN TEAMS.TSX

    // session
    const session = await sessionStorage.getSession(request.headers.get('Cookie'));

    if (!session.get('token')) {
        return redirectWithToast(`/`, { message: "You don’t have access!", type: "error" } )
    }

    // data: the same data fetch in teams.tsx!
    const teams = await fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

    if (teams.length === 0) { // DIFF WITH TEAMS.TSX
        [...]
        return redirectWithToast(`/teams`, { message: "Team not found!", type: "error" } )
    }

    return { session, teams };
}

export default function Teams() {
    const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

    console.log(data.session)
    console.log(data.teams)
}
```

Comment: Is each loader instantiating its own fetch request to the same endpoint? See if you can lift the loader to the single root/parent/index "route" such that it's called only once regardless which child route is accessed. An alternative may be to have each loader call ***the same*** fetching logic that can maintain control over network resource calls. Please try to [edit] the post to include an actual [mcve] of the code you are working with so we can provide more specific help if necessary as it's rather difficult to assess issues in code we can't see.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.